# Can I use just few servers to get lot of network connections?

Tags: linux, tcp, network-programming

I am trying to get as much network connections from one machine as I can, using few machines. I just want to be sure that establishing many connections between servers will give me similar results as having many connections with different server?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and some issues related to that are called the [C10K problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C10k_problem) !

However, a connection to `localhost` is not the same as a distant remote one: the latency and the bandwidth are quite different.

Maybe you want some [web server benchmarking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_server_benchmarking) ? There are some tools for that!

Comment: Well, I wasn't precise: I have 2 servers A and B, and my question is, that if I will establish lot of connections between them will server A behave simillary if it would have connections from many different servers?

Comment: Not exactly, since the latency & bandwidth would be different than in the case of a real web server accessed by many clients worldwide

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Well, in my case - its ok - I will try to get at least 100k from single machine.
PS. I was studying near Socrates Starynkiewicz square in Warsaw :)